# Shading issues in the Mirror and Subdivision Modifier

Tags: modeling, 3d-view, edit-mode, object-mode, 3d-cursor

After removing the bevels I created, it still seemed to be having that pinching. In addition, I tried to make sure the center of the mesh is completely flattened out. Let alone, I still have trouble trying to round out the back for better topology with no luck. If there is anyone who can help me, that would be much appreciated. I sent the project file.

[image: Mic Stand Shading Issue]

[image]

Comment: Hello could you please share your file?

Comment: You probably have an internal face between the two halves of the modifier. Go into Wireframe mode (Shift-Z) in Edit mode, select Face mode and delete any face between the halves.

Comment: I already did that unfortunately.

Comment: As @moonboots says we'll need to see your Blend file in that case. You can share it via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the link on that page. Then [edit](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/311506/edit) your question here and paste the link into it.

Comment: The file format you shared is not a .blend file but a .blend1 file which is no use for us. But my guess is that the merge value of the mirror modifier isn't small enough

Answer (score 1):

There are doubled vertices here:

[image]

Comment: I got that taken care of. It fixed the bulge from the front and back sides of the mesh. How do I round out the mesh so It's less blocky now?

Comment: This is another question. The rule here is to ask one question on one subject. Please ask another one.

Comment: Ok, I understand.